# ElasticSearch failed to parse date field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following query that I'm trying to run on Elasticsearch 5.6 in Kibana Dev Tools:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "inserted": {
                  "gt": "Thu Aug 20 09:01:31 +0100 2020"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the response I'm getting is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse date field [Thu Aug 20 09:01:31 +0100 2020] with format [EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "can_match",
    "grouped": true,
```

The datetime format looks correct to me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also share the nature of the field 'inserted'? type and a sample value

Comment: Please share the index mapping as well in the description

Answer (score 3):

**In Short:**  'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy' is the correct format.

**Details:**

1. Elastic Search uses Joda library for formatting DateTime.

Excerpt from [ES Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-date-format.html)

> Completely customizable date formats are supported. The syntax for these is explained in the Joda docs.

2. Try formatting DateTime with the pattern you are using "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy" using Joda library. Programming language is **Java**

> ```
> DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
> DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime("Thu Aug 20 09:01:31 +0100 2020");
> ```

**It is resulting in below exception :**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
> format: "Thu Aug 20 09:01:31 +0100 2020" is malformed at "+0100 2020"
> at
> org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)

**Deduction:** There is something wrong with the format defined by 'ZZZ'

From [JodaDoc](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html)

> Z       time zone offset/id          zone          -0800

3. Based on the investigation correct format is "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" and not "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy".
4. Considering #3 define format in your mapping like

> ```
> {
>   "mappings": {
>     "_doc":{
>     "properties": {
>       "inserted":{
>         "type": "date",
>         "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: This is the solution. Had the exact same formatting pattern and problem, and this fixed it. Thanks!